# Overwrite files with condiction Izpack

Tags: java, installation, izpack

I have an installer that put some files in the client machine, so i want the same installer be the update installer, so i want to put a condition if these files already exists i'll show a dialog to the user choose if he wants to replace or not the files.

My izpack code is like this

```xml
<pack name="Product" required="yes">
            <file src="../@{project.artifactId}.jar" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH" />
            <fileset dir="../resources" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/resources">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset>

            <fileset dir="dependency" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/lib">
                <include name="**/*" />
            </fileset>

            <fileset dir="../resources/icons" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH">
                <include name="favicon.ico" />
            </fileset>

</pack>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using the attribute **override** with value **asktrue** like the code below

You can ignore some files from your source dir too with the tag exclude

```xml
<file src="../resources/myfile.properties" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/resources" override="asktrue" />
<fileset dir="../resources" targetdir="$INSTALL_PATH/resources">
  <exclude name="**/myfile.properties" />
  <include name="**/*" />
</fileset>
```

Comment: where did you `put a condition if these files already exists` and `show a dialog to the user choose if he wants to replace or not the files` ?  
`<exclude>` doesnt do much to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: in the attribute override you can put the value "asktrue" here is the docs http://docs.codehaus.org/display/IZPACK/Pack+FileSet

Comment: alright. but also, shouldn't your `solved the problem using the following code` contain `override="asktrue"`